# No permission to write a file from task scheduler?

Tags: file, batch-file, windows-7, permissions, scheduled-tasks

I got a batch file that will run a c++ program and output to a file with ">" redirection. This file is to be run by task scheduler.

I found out that when the batch file is ran from task scheduler, it claims "access is denied". The batch file runs fine until it reaches that ">" redirection part. (I see that the whole batch can run finely without ">") I have tried running the task scheduler as an administrator as well, but I still got "access is denied".

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you redirecting output somewhere in the drive in which Windows is installed ?

Comment: Nope I am outputting to a directory in D Drive  and that's not where windows is installed.

Answer (score 6):

For those who can't write file into the relative path.

Try go to property of the task. 
`property` > `action` > `edit your action`.

Change the "Start in" to your EXE　working path.

Comment: I had tried almost all possible solutions, and already running under administrators. However still it was failing to run the exe. Finally it ran when put the same path in "Start In".

Answer (score 1):

There may be quite a few reasons of it, first check below points:

1. Check whether the user who has scheduled batch script to run in Task
   scheduler has admin access on the system or not.
2. Give that user full Share/NTFS permissions on the "RedirectedFolders" and all of the sub
   folders as well.you can manually propagate all permissions down to the folders.
3. The user should have read and write
   permissions along with full control to the "RedirectedFolders" .