# Windows Task Scheduler and sdf Database

Tags: c#, windows, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, scheduled-tasks

I have a relatively simple C# application which grabs some data from a website and writes it into an sdf database file.

The application itself works just fine - however if i run the application as a scheduled task with the windows task scheduler it does not add anything to the database (it still shows up as running in the task manager, as intended).

So just to clarify it again:
Manually starting the exe works just fine (click or command window), but starting it as a task (no matter if scheduled or manually) it runs but does not add anything to the database.

What differences are there between starting an exe manually compared to a task which has a "start program" action?

Comment: Try to run the application as a user with Admin privileges, the program might not have write access to the SDF file.

Comment: It may be an issue related to file permissions. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744604/no-permission-to-write-a-file-from-task-scheduler

Comment: Ok, I've set the task to be run from the local user account which has administrator access and checked "require highest permission".
In the compatibility settings of the file I've checked "run this prog as admin" (for all users).
I've also set the file permissions for every single file, folder and subfolder so that "everyone" and my user account have full control about everything.

Still no difference.

Comment: Connectionstring, please!

Comment: There you go:

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SpritpreisContext" connectionString="Data Source=SpritpreisDB.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly this is not really the perfect answer for the question, but I have now got it working by using an SQL Server (MS-SQL 2014 Express).

Apparently .sdf files and the windows task scheduler aren't best friends.