# Windows Task Scheduler running python script writing to file

Tags: python, windows, task, scheduler

I have two scripts running on schedule in Windows Task scheduler.

First one writes new .csv file to disc, second one adds lines to existing file. (separate files, unrelated)

Both tasks are setup in Task Scheduler exactly the same way, however the second script, that suppose to add new lines to existing file, runs (command line output looks fine), but does not write anything to the file.

When run manually from VSC or command line it works fine.

Code:

```
with open('database.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    [wr.writerow(line) for line in temp_data]
    print()
    print('Write successful.')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No permission to write a file from task scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744604/no-permission-to-write-a-file-from-task-scheduler)

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I've just noticed that I've specified the path in the working script, but not in the "broken" one. I either have to modify [Start in] option in task scheduler or add path to file in the script.